# Odoo can’t find the pandas module even though it is installed

Tags: python, pandas, odoo

I have a problem with Odoo every time I try to install Open HRMS add on and it says that it cannot find the pandas module even though it is installed and I have tried using it manually without Odoo. Ive installed pandas using pip and using anaconda and both ways did not work.

Comment: Do you use docker?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please be more precise. [Edit] your question and describe how you installed which modules and what do you mean by "did not work". What command do you enter, what happens, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].